# Django Access ForeignKey object fields from template tags

Tags: python, django

In my current django app template I have one Car model (with FK  to CategoryCar) and one CategoryCar model that has price_category field.

In my car template, for generate my select field I do:

```
{% for value, field in form.fk_category_car.field.choices %}
       <option value="{{ value }}">{{ field }} - {{ HERE I need price category }} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I access to price field of related CarCategory objects?

Another question: How can I have one ForeignKey field that must shows only values filtered by previous input field?

here the real model of my application (you can think Contract as Car and CheckOutPlace as CategoryCar:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Data contratto")
    # Checkout info.
    checkout_place = models.ForeignKey(CheckOutPlace, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Luogo consegna",
                                   related_name="checkout_place_contracts")
class CheckOutPlace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Nome Luogo")
    price_checkout = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Prezzo Consegna")
```

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: I had invented at "runtime" :)
Substantially In a ViewForm of one of my model I have a foreign key field that shows the related elements. With these elements I need not only to load pk and name, but also a price field.

Comment: I mean, can you post the contents of your `models.py`

Comment: I've added my model ;)